# Bash script FOR in create folder

Tags: linux, for-loop, linux-mint

System Linux Mint. 3-4 lines. Please inspect the code. And is it possible to somehow write the cycle in one line, as I tried below?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd MyFolder
name_folder=('MyFolder1' 'MyFolder1' 'MyFolder3')
for i in ${name_folder} do mkdir $i
cd MyFolder3
FOR %%A IN (txt1.txt,txt2.txt,txt3.txt) DO touch "%%~A"
FOR %%A IN (json1.json,json2.json) DO touch "%%~A"
FOR %%A IN (NewFolder1,NewFolder1,NewFolder3) DO mkdir "%%~A"
ls
mv json1.json ../Myfolder1
mv json1.json ../Myfolder1
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `cd'
./myscript.sh: line 5: `cd MyFolder3'

Comment: Can you state what exactly you need to achieve with the script. Also, the syntax for `for loop` is wrong. You are missing a `done` at the end of the loop completion.
Seems like you are trying to convert windows Batch programming to Bash syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir MyFolder
cd MyFolder
name_folder="MyFolder1 MyFolder2 MyFolder3"
for i in ${name_folder}; do mkdir $i; done
cd MyFolder3
F="txt1.txt txt2.txt txt3.txt"
for A in $F; do touch "$A"; done
F="json1.json json2.json"
for A in $F; do touch "$A"; done
F="NewFolder1 NewFolder2 NewFolder3"
for A in $F ; do mkdir "$A"; done
ls
mv json1.json ../Myfolder1
mv json2.json ../Myfolder1
```